# How delete refresh login in after logout in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, authentication, logout

my logout function works (we display login page), but when i click on button disconnect the login page will be displayed but it will refresh 2 times.
how to fix this error to display login page without refresh
here is my function:

```
var _logOut = function () {    
  localStorageService.remove('authorizationData');
  $state.go("login", {}, { reload: true });
  $window.location.reload();
  // _authentication.isAuth = true;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that `$window.location.reload()` is necessary.
Try removing it.

Comment: yes I want to delete, but when click on the arrow flip (left corner of browser,) it returns to my account,  and I don't want to return to my account

Comment: This should be another question. If you want to prevent access to a certain state you have to protect it; check the docs about Transition Hooks of UI-Router: https://ui-router.github.io/guide/transitionhooks